# How do we use our own dictionary in aspell instead of the default dictionary?

Tags: r, nlp, data-analysis, data-science, aspell

Can you tell me the format of specifying the dictionaries in the aspell function. Also what is the extension of dictionaries supposed to be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider reading [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question. Also, have you tried `?aspell`, because to me it seems that the help page contains the information that you are looking for.

Comment: @Laterow I followed the instructions as given in help page, but it throws an error saying dictionaries not found. Also I wanted to know how to create my own dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

To make your own dictionary in R try these steps:

"It is possible to employ additional R level dictionaries. Currently, these are files with extension ‘.rds’ obtained by serializing character vectors of word lists using saveRDS. If such dictionaries are employed, they are combined into a single word list file which is then used as the spell checker's personal dictionary (option -p): hence, the default personal dictionary is not used in this case."

To use the dictionaries argument in aspell try follow these requirements:

You should use "a character vector of names or file paths of additional R level dictionaries to use. Elements with no path separator specify R system dictionaries (in subdirectory ‘share/dictionaries’ of the R home directory). The file extension (currently, only ‘.rds’) can be omitted."

Source: http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/aspell

Hopefully this helps!